# Python - Regex and Webscrape

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract all the dog names from a webpage. I would like to be able to scrape the page, append the names (if new) to a list, and eventually be able to send a notification if the list size has changed at all.

I am currently trying to extract the names for now. I am having trouble extracting the name after the phrase "My name is " from the page.

The code I have so far is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'http://petharbor.com/results.asp?searchtype=ADOPT&start=3%20&friends=1&samaritans=1&nosuccess=0&rows=25&imght=200&imgres=thumb&tWidth=200&view=sysadm.v_chmp&bgcolor=b7b7b7&text=ffffff&link=ffffff&alink=4400ff&vlink=ffffff&fontface=arial&fontsize=12&col_hdr_bg=000066&col_hdr_fg=ffffff&SBG=000066&zip=61802&miles=10&shelterlist=%27CHMP%27&atype=&where=type_DOG&PAGE=1'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

key = "My name is "
puppies = []

names = soup.find_all(text=re.compile("My name is(.*)"))
```

I am trying to slice the content to only list each individual name and then append that to a list I have (puppies). Is there a way to split the list and then slice each part? Or, is it better to again run a regex through that list?

I think I found a solution so far:

```
for name in names:
    puppies.append(name[10:])
```

This seems to work.

Now that I am able to scrape I am trying to build lists to keep names: old, new, and newest. I would like to run the function and check for new names against old lists and append the names to the "newer" lists. I am having trouble running the names through a check and re-assign. Can anyone help me understand a method to get this to work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time
from twilio.rest import Client

url = 'http://petharbor.com/results.asp?searchtype=ADOPT&start=3%20&friends=1&samaritans=1&nosuccess=0&rows=25&imght=200&imgres=thumb&tWidth=200&view=sysadm.v_chmp&bgcolor=b7b7b7&text=ffffff&link=ffffff&alink=4400ff&vlink=ffffff&fontface=arial&fontsize=12&col_hdr_bg=000066&col_hdr_fg=ffffff&SBG=000066&zip=61802&miles=10&shelterlist=%27CHMP%27&atype=&where=type_DOG&PAGE=1'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content

account_sid = ("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
auth_token = ("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

names = soup.find_all(text=re.compile("My name is(.*)"))

old = []
new = []
newest = []

def check():
    for name in names:
        if name not in old:
            old.append(name[11:-2])
            if name in old:
                continue

def new_check():
    for name in names:
        if name in old:
            continue
        if name not in new and name not in old:
            new.append(name[11:-2])

    for name in names:
        if name in old and name in new:
            continue
        if name not in old and name not in new:
            newest.append(name[11:-2])

    #client.api.account.messages.create(to = "+xxxxxxxxxxx",
                                        #from_= "+xxxxxxxxxxx",
                                        #body = "Here are some new dogs:" + str(new))

    #client.api.account.messages.create(to="+xxxxxxxxxxx",
                                       #from_="+xxxxxxxxxxx",
                                       #body=("There are " + str(num_newest) + " new puppies"), media_url = 'http://petharbor.com/results.asp?searchtype=ADOPT&start=3%20&friends=1&samaritans=1&nosuccess=0&rows=25&imght=200&imgres=thumb&tWidth=200&view=sysadm.v_chmp&bgcolor=b7b7b7&text=ffffff&link=ffffff&alink=4400ff&vlink=ffffff&fontface=arial&fontsize=12&col_hdr_bg=000066&col_hdr_fg=ffffff&SBG=000066&zip=61802&miles=10&shelterlist=%27CHMP%27&atype=&where=type_DOG&PAGE=1')

    #client.api.account.messages.create(to = "+xxxxxxxxxxx",
                                        #from_= "+xxxxxxxxxxx",
                                        #body = "Here are some new names:" + str(newest))


num_old = len(old)
num_new = len(new)
num_newest = len(newest)

while True:
    check()
    print("Old List: " + str(old))
    print("Number of old: " + str(num_old))
    time.sleep(20)
    new_check()
    print("New List: " + str(new))
    print("Number of new: " + str(num_new))
    print("Newest List: " + str(newest))
    print("Number of newest: " + str(num_newest))
    time.sleep(20)
```

Comment: Note that you can do it directly using the XPath functions `substring-after` and `substring-before`. In other words you don't need a regex at all.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, BeautifulSoup doesn't support XPath expressions. OP should try [lxml](http://lxml.de/) which does support

Comment: Why not do something like: names = oldnames; for name in newnames: if newname in oldnames: names.append(name)